# MVVM command error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am very much new to WPF MVVM pattern especially `commands`

`ViewModel` that contains Command

```
public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(FuncToCall); }
}

private object FuncToCall(object context)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The button was Clicked", "");
    return null;
}
```

and **RelayCommandClass.cs**

```
private Action<object> _action;

public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
{
    _action = action;
}
```

on compiling i get `FuncToCall(object)' has the wrong return type`

Thank you All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio adds the wrong method signature when you write the name of a method and click on its suggestion to create the method for you. Change the signature to this and all will be well:

```
private void FuncToCall(object context)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The button was Clicked", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make FuncToCall() return type `Void` and remove `return` statement.

```
private void FuncToCall(object context)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The button was Clicked", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method FuncToCall should not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

FuncToCall() method should not any return type and remove return statement.